# Determinant of a circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am interested in the calculation of the determinant of a $N\times N$ matrix with the following shape (for $N=5$)
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b & 0 & 0 & b \\
b & a & b & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & a & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & b & a & b \\
b & 0 & 0 & b & a \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
As the matrix is diagonally dominant, I know it is nonsingular.

Is there a general result for the calculation of $\det A$ for any value of $N$? If so, how can it be derived?

Comment: [Yes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Determinant)

Comment: Note that it is only diagonally dominant in the case that $a > 2|b|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the formula from the [link in the comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Determinant), we have the following.  Let $\omega$ denote an $N$th root of unity, then 
$$
\det(A) = \prod_{j=0}^{N-1} [a + b(\omega^j + \omega^{-j})] = 
\prod_{j=0}^{N-1} [a + 2b\cos(2\pi j/N)].
$$
Hopefully this is sufficient for your purposes.